# Query about oracle sql aggregate function

Tags: sql, oracle, function, aggregate

I have started learning sql database just from 1 week and have a query about aggregate function..
I want to use two add marks of students and want to sort their totals by minimum to max.

I have tried

```
SELECT student_name,min(sum(marks))
FROM STUDENTS a,STUDENT b
WHERE a.student_name=b.student_name
GROUP BY student_name
```

But I got error in the first line
Not a single-group group function

plz tell me what will be the right code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Select Student_name, min(marks)
from (
SELECT student_name,sum(marks) marks
FROM STUDENTS a,STUDENT b
WHERE a.student_name=b.student_name
GROUP BY student_name)
GROUP BY student_name
```

Comment: Yeah..Working.. Thanq.. :) Can u tell me how did u do that?? I mean can u xplain it..?? Plzzzz..

Comment: To the extent I know you can't apply both functions at same time... so by using sub query we are extacting sum first then min...

Comment: There's no such option..! Where's that option??

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to need a `join` for this query, unless you want filtering.  (And, if you do use a `join` then use explicit join syntax).  Assuming `marks` is from the second table, I think you want something like:

```
SELECT s.student_name, sum(b.marks)
FROM STUDENT s
GROUP BY s.student_name
ORDER BY sum(b.marks);
```